# How to get the return value from a custom command in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I am writing a long test so I added the most reusable part to a Command Folder, however, I need access to a certain return value. How would I get the return value from the command?

Comment: Hi. You can expose it by wrapping the final result, so it becomes the value yielded by your custom command. In our callback `.then(() => { ... cy.wrap(salesContractumber)})`.  (P.S. for the future, please do not attach screenshots with your code. You better attach it as a snippet, written form. It will be much easier to read and provide potential solutions ;))

Comment: @Tester Please add your code in your question and avoid using images of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly returning the salesContractNumber, wrap it and then return it like this:

Your custom command:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('addStandardGrainSalesContract', () => {
  //Rest of the code
  return cy.wrap(salesContractNumber)
})
```

In your test you can do this:

```js
cy.addStandardGrainSalesContract().then((salesContractNumber) => {
cy.get(FixingsAddPageSelectors.ContractNumberField).type(salesContractNumber)
})
```

Comment: This worked for the issue I was having. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you need to return the value from the last `.then()`.

Cypress puts the results of the commands onto the queue for you, and trailing `.then()` sections can modify the results.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('addStandardGrainSalesContract', () => {
  
  let salesContractNumber;

  cy.get('SalesContractsAddSelectors.SalesContractNumber').should($h2 => {
    ...
    salesContractNumber = ...
  })
  .then(() => {
    ...
    return salesContractNumber
  })
})

cy.addStandardGrainSalesContract().then(salesContractumber => {
  ...
```

Or this should work also

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('addStandardGrainSalesContract', () => {
  
  cy.get('SalesContractsAddSelectors.SalesContractNumber').should($h2 => {
    ...
    const salesContractNumber = ...
    return salesContractNumber;  // pass into .then()
  })
  .then(salesContractNumber => {
    ...
    return salesContractNumber  // returns to outer code
  })
})

cy.addStandardGrainSalesContract().then(salesContractumber => {
  ...
```

---

**Extra notes:**

```js
const salesContractHeader = $h2.text()  // don't need Cypress.$()
const salesContractNumber = salesContractHeader.split(' ').pop() // take last item in array
```